# DIVS and IMAGES pulled from db show up as normal but text does not

Tags: html, css, database, google-chrome

I am completely baffled. I am constructing a portfolio site where images with their respective titles and descriptions are pulled from the database and displayed in a nice gallery.

The effect I am trying to achieve is to have text appear on the image when hovered.

When the data is pulled from the database the images show up fine, whereas the text is nowhere to be seen. The div meant to contain the text shows up on the image which is what I desire but there is no text to be seen.

Even on the inspect view on CHROME the text shows up inside the div.

I have copied and pasted from the inspect view to another page so the content wont be pulled from the database and the text shows up fine.

Sorry for the long paragraph but it needed explanation so you guys know what I've tried already.

Thanks!

```
           <?php

            $query = "SELECT * FROM `portfolio` ORDER BY `pf_id` DESC";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

            $list = '';

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                //Linking the variables
                $id = $row["pf_id"];
                $title = $row["pf_title"];
                $desc = $row["pf_desc"];
                $pfimg = $row["pf_html"];

                $date = $row["pf_date"];
                $time = strtotime($date);
                $datemdy = date("F j, Y", $time);
                $datetime = date("g:i A", $time);

                $list .= '<a href="pfpiece.php?id='.$id.'">' . $pfimg . '</a>';

            }

        mysqli_close($con);

        ?>
        <div class="pf-container">
            <p><?php echo $list; ?></p>
        </div>
```

This will generate this piece of html which works fine on its own just not when pulled from database.

```
<div class="pf-img-wrap">
<img src="/uploads/portfolio_items/IMG/1.jpg">
<div class="pf-img-title">2</div>
</div>
```

The CSS for this:

```
.pf-container 
{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size:0;
}

.pf-img-wrap 
{
    width:calc(100% / 3);
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
}

.pf-img-wrap img
{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:40%;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;

    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}

.pf-img-wrap img:hover 
{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(65%);
}

.pf-img-title {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:60;
    color: #fff;
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:10px;
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
    top:0;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code snippets and perhaps also the reference in the web inspector to which you are referring to?

Comment: How are you implementing the hover behavior? With javascript? CSS?

Comment: if you used position on img and not the text, then it might be a clue, ...  untill you set up a snippet here or online that reproduce your issue, else no efficient answer can be given just guess play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the font size to zero in your CSS rule:

```
.pf-container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

So set it to something other than zero for those divs (perhaps in the rules you already have for `.pf-img-title`) and there ya go.

Comment: I feel so stupid thank you, added that to get rid of white space earlier. Been working on this around the clock probably why I didn't notice, thanks!!